# django-rest-framework get_schema_view: TypeError: Object of type 'Document' is not JSON serializable

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, openapi

`django-rest-framework` package from version 3.9 now renders api schema view in yaml format by default [Announcement](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.9-announcement/)

When I try to render it in JSON format as in example https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.9-announcement/#built-in-openapi-schema-support

```
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONOpenAPIRenderer
from rest_framework.schemas import get_schema_view


schema_view = get_schema_view(
    title="API",
    public=True,
    urlconf='api.urls',
    renderer_classes=[JSONOpenAPIRenderer]
)


urlpatterns = [
    url("^schema/", schema_view)
]
```

I'm getting:

```
TypeError: Object of type 'Document' is not JSON serializable
```

Versions of packages: `Django==2.2.12`, `djangorestframework==3.11.0`, `openapi-codec==1.3.2`

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get what I wanted using `CoreJSONRenderer` instead.